# Passing formdata, input text data, and dropdown data in $.ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass values from a FormData (containing a CSV file), input text, and dropdown (select element) to a php script. However, when I tried to run it, it returned a message that says

> TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement
>   interface FormData

I'm using `$.ajax()` to avoid refresh.

I am only passing a CSV file using `formData` 
I don't know how to pass CSV file together with the data from text field and dropdown.

```
function addNewSection(){
    var sectionName =$("#modalInput_addSectionTitle").val(); //value from an input text
    var sectionTeacher = $("#modalDrpDown_selectSectionTeacher").val(); //value from a dropdown

    var csvFile =  $('#browseFiles')[0].files[0]; //value from a file input
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('csvFile', csvFile);
    $.ajax({
        url:"controller/add_section.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            formData, 
            modalInput_addSectionTitle : sectionName,
        },
        success: function(isSuccessful){
            console.log("Is Successful: "+isSuccessful);
            $('#container_modalAddNewSection').hide();
        },
        error: function (x, e) {
            handleError(x,e);
        }
    });
}
```

I'd appreciate any suggestion.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please share the code snippet as a pen file so its easy to debug and get you a solution

Comment: When sending a formData object that is the only thing you can send. You can't make it part of another object for jQuery to try to serialize. Read up on how to upload files with jQuery ajax